# span tag height in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

Using CSS,

I'm trying to specify the height of a `span` tag in Firefox, but it's just not accepting it (IE does).

Firefox accepts the `height` if I use a `div`, but the problem with using a `div` is the annoying line break after it, which I can't have in this particular instance.

I tried setting the CSS style attribute of:

```
display: inline
```

for the `div`, but Firefox seems to revert that to `span` behavior anyway and ignores the `height` attribute once again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<style>
#div1 { float:left; height:20px; width:20px; }
#div2 { float:left; height:30px; width:30px }
</style>

<div id="div1">FirstDiv</div>
<div id="div2">SecondDiv</div>
```

As long as the container for whatever is holding `div's` 1 and 2 is wide enough for them to fit, this should be fine.

Answer (score 32):

You can set any element to `display: inline-block` to allow it to receive a height or width. This also allows you to apply any other "block styles" to an element.

One thing to be careful about however is that Firefox 2 does not support this property. Firefox 3 is the first Mozilla-based browser to support this property. All other browsers support this property, including Internet Explorer.

Keep in mind that `inline-block` does not allow you to set text alignment inside the element on Firefox if running in quirks mode. All other browsers allow this as far as I know. If you want to set text-alignment while running in quirks mode, you'll have to use the property `-moz-inline-stack` instead of `inline-block`. Keep in mind this is a Mozilla-only property so you'll have to do some browser detection to ensure only Mozilla gets this, while other browsers get the standard `inline-block`.

Comment: You can get away without browser sniffing by specifying both options, with the -moz one second. Non-mozilla browsers will ignore the -moz option, but in Firefox it will override the first setting. "display:inline-block; display:-moz-inline-stack;"

Answer (score 17):

Inline elements can't have heights (nor widths) like that. SPANs are already `display: inline` by default. Internet Explorer is actually the broken browser in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're displaying it inline, the height should be set at the height of your line-height attribute.

Depending on how it's laid out, you could always use float:left or float:right on the span/div to prevent the line break.  But if you want it in the middle of a sentence, that option is out.

Answer (score 1):

You can only change the height (and width) of a span element when it is set to `display: block;`. This is because it is an inline element normally. `div` is set to `display: block;` normally.

A solution could be to use:

```
<div style="background: #f00;">
    Text <span style="padding: 14px 0 14px 0; background: #ff0;">wooo</span> text.
</div>
```

Comment: Not only. It applies also to display:inline-block, display:table and few others.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that 'display: inline' can't get a height associated because, being inline, it gets its height from its the content. Anyway, how do you define the height of a box that is broken at the end of a line?

You might try to set 'line-height' instead, or if this doesn't work to your satisfaction, set a padding:

```
/* makes the whole box higher by inserting a space between the border and the content */
padding: 0.5em 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

To set height of span following should work in firefox

```css
span {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`height` in `em` = `relative line-height`

for example `height:1.1em` with `line-height:1.1`

= 100% filled

Answer (score 0):

text alignment inside the element you can adjust using the padding and block-inline attributes. display:inline-block; padding-top:3px; for example